What exactly happens as light is exiting a fiber?
I am currently trying to learn the fundamentals of optical fibers, however most literature stops within the fiber itself.
What I gathered is that as the light comes out, it is no longer guided and radiates in the first fundamental form (Gaussian).
Now if I had to try to model some system, say put a photodiode in front of it, how would I compute the intensity profile there?
My guess is that I model it using Fresnel or Fraunhofer diffraction (depending on the distance) and somehow find the mode overlap at that distance.
I am not sure if my reasoning is correct throughout this.

Unless there’s a significant distance between the fiber and the diode you will need Fresnel.
